# how to add arguments to button click that will only change part of cmd

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments, buttonclick

I'm trying to build up my first `c#` program and I got stuck at changing part of the button click arguments.

I need `ssid` and `key` to be able to be changed:

```
strCmdText = "/C netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=changeme key=changeme keyUsage=persistent & netsh wlan start hostednetwork";
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;



namespace wifion
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "/C netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=changeme key=123123123 keyUsage=persistent & netsh wlan start hostednetwork";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strCmdText;
            strCmdText = "/C netsh wlan stop hostednetwork";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wifigo 1.0.\nWritten by: Atilla Eyice", "About");
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are the values for these two fields coming from?  I assume `textBox1` and `comboBox1`?

Comment: for ssid textBox1 and for key textBox2 i have added combo box acidntly

Comment: I've edited the answer given by @MajkeloDev to reflect your source for these two values.  His solution should provide what you need.  Because the two `TextBox` controls are accessible to the button's click event, you don't need to pass them as parameters - just access them directly as shown.

Comment: Did You found Your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

```
string ssid = this.textBox1.Text;
string key = this.textBox2.Text;

strCmdText = string.format("/C netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid={0} key={1} keyUsage=persistent & netsh wlan start hostednetwork", ssid, key);
```